# Problems inserting new data into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do an if else insert into one table from another (a table type).

I am having problems where basically the first time the script runs it adds all data into the table OK but then if something is added to the source data afterwards, it does not add the new record and I don't know why.

I can't include the exact code but it looks like this...

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
Set Target.Desc = Source.Desc
From @source source
WHERE Target.AccountNumber = Source.AccountNumber

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
   INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(AccountNumber, Desc)
      SELECT Source.AccountNumber, Source.Desc
      FROM @Source Source
```

I have also tried a traditional if else insert but it had the same results.

Can you see anything wrong that might be stopping the newly added records from being inserted?

Comment: it's a user-defined table type with the data.

Comment: Does it only contain one row? Or at least exclusively "new" or exclusively "old" records? If you have a mix of new and old it definitely won't work as desired. Also please state version of SQL Server. If 2008+ you can use `MERGE`

Comment: @connersz Can you provide table schema  for both tables ?

Comment: If there are rows present, your @@ROWCOUNT from the update statement will not be 0 anymore. e.g. if target has 10 rows, and source now has 11, 10 rows will be updated, making rowcount 10, not 0.
This will only work if source contains _one_ row only, and whether that is the case is unclear :)

Comment: No the source contains multiple rows with a mix of old (which needs updating) and new (which needs inserting) data. How can I get around this problem without doing a loop?

Comment: You cannot, because yuo cannot treat all records the same way, which your current code is doing. See @MartinSmith 's comment, possibly you can use MERGE

Comment: But won't the merge just synchronise both tables? In the source table, I need to be able to update it from multiple sources and not lose that data.

Comment: @connersz - No. `MERGE` will allow you to update the matching rows and insert the non matching rows as your current code appears to be attempting.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code will only work correctly if `@source` contains either all existing or all new rows.

You can use `MERGE` when this is not the case

```
MERGE CUSTOMER AS target
USING @source AS source
ON ( target.AccountNumber = source.AccountNumber )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET [Desc] = source.[Desc]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (AccountNumber, [Desc])
  VALUES (AccountNumber, [Desc]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this instead of using @@ROWCOUNT

```
-- update existing customers
UPDATE c
SET c.Desc = Source.Desc
FROM @source source
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c ON c.AccountNumber = Source.AccountNumber

-- insert new customers
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(AccountNumber, Desc)
SELECT Source.AccountNumber, Source.Desc
FROM @Source Source
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER c ON Source.AccountNumber = c.AccountNumber
WHERE c.AccountNumber IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

@@ROWCOUNT value contains the count of affected rows. the insert statement works only if all the records are new. and it does not go for updation. if any of the record got updated, it would not go for  insertion even the source contains new records

If your requirement is to update existing records and Insert New records from source , you can use the below code.

```
-- update existing Rows
UPDATE CUSTOMER 
SET CUSTOMER.Desc = SOURCE.Desc
from @SOURCE Source
WHERE Source.AccountNumber=CUSTOMER.AccountNumber

-- Insert New Data
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (AccountNumber, Desc)
SELECT s.AccountNumber, s.Desc
FROM @Source Source
WHERE not exists( SELECT 1
                  FROM CUSTOMER 
                  WHERE CUSTOMER.AccountNumber=Source.AccountNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- update all existing rows
update c set 
    c.Desc = s.Desc
from CUSTOMER c
join @source s on s.AccountNumber=c.AccountNumber

-- insert all missing rows
insert into CUSTOMER (AccountNumber, Desc)
select s.AccountNumber, s.Desc
from @Source s
where not exists(
    select *
    from CUSTOMER c
    where c.AccountNumber=s.AccountNumber
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time, there is no data in your target so @@rowcount is 0.
Next time, the update updates all data and @@rowcount is not 0 and you get no data inserted.
You should not use @@rowcount but do what Andrew suggest:  do both UPDATE and INSERT
or MERGE (do both in one statement)